# Reading a GUID string as a GUID from executing a SQL script throws an invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

We are executing a SQL script and reading the results using a `SQLDataReader`. This line is throwing an `InvalidCastException`:

```
reader.GetGuid(1)
```

The object being returned is a GUID as a string (`"6efbef12-145a-42fc-b1b0-c53170a284e4"`).

If I do this:

```
Guid.Parse(reader.GetString(1))
```

then the GUID is returned successfully.

Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of type mismatch between column SQL Server type and .NET type you want to retrieve its value as. As written in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getguid?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) for `SqlDataReader.GetGuid`, no conversion is performed to retrieve the GUID, the column value must already have the appropriate type. From the [mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) of types between SQL Server and .NET we see that required type is `uniqueidentifier`, whereas, considering that getting the column value as string and parsing it to GUID is successful, your column has some string type (e.g. `nvarchar`).

Comment: So how come it works in most cases when reading it as a GUID but it is a SQL string and sometimes (like the example above) it doesn’t?

Comment: @IanHannah In what cases does it work? When using `SqlDataReader` it shouldn't, as explained in the answer. In some other libraries/languages maybe implicit conversion between SQL and language types allows this.

Comment: I was convinced that I did return a GUID as an nvarchar and it worked but I cannot prove this now :) Thanks for your response.